# Identify a post-apocalyptic movie about a group of heroes fighting a gang to get a factory back

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

I am trying to identify a movie I saw as a child in the late 1980's or 1990.

- The movie looked post-apocalyptic similar to Mad Max
- In it, a community ran a factory or a refinery that they defended with rifles from another group
- The attacking group was made up of bikers but had an elite unit of stormtrooper-like soldiers clad in black armor (maybe with shields) that was bulletproof and marched in a wall formation
- In the movie, the first attack by the bikers is beaten back but the second, by the black stormtroopers, allows them to capture the factory/refinery
- The heroes escape the factory and journey to find a way to defeat the troopers
- They come back and defeat the troopers and the bikers and free the community
- The movie could be European or American

The movie is not The Road Warrior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might this be ***[2020 Texas Gladiators](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083565/)*** (1983)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Texas_Gladiators):

> *2020 Texas Gladiators* (Italian: *Texas 2000*) is an Italian science fiction action film co-directed by Joe D'Amato and George Eastman.

> After bitter wars and natural disasters, the earth is devastated, depopulated and chaotic; morality and law no longer exist. Marauding gangs terrorize the last gatherings of peace-loving people, who often gather around churches. Only a small group of volunteers - the Rangers - fight back against injustice.
>
> In Texas in 2020, degenerate villains raid a monastery in which pretty Maida took refuge, when five roving Rangers show up. The battle-hardened men quickly succeed in repelling the attackers and restoring order. However, during the incident, one of her saviors named Catch Dog falls into disgrace as he tries to rape Maida. He is eventually rejected by his comrades. Later, Ranger Nexus separates from his friends, taking Maida with him.
>
> **Five years later, Nexus and Maida live with their little daughter a seemingly safe life in the settlement of Free Town. In addition to basic services, the community operates a power plant and uranium mine. The village's energy reserves soon lure in dark outlaws. One day, disaster strikes as Catch Dog manages to bring down Free Town with his gang.** Catch Dog himself acts on behalf of the "Black One", a totalitarian ruler who subjugates the population with his thugs. In an attempt to resist, Nexus dies. The able-bodied men are enslaved and used as laborers in the uranium production, the women are sold to different bars in the area.
>
> **At some point, the three remaining Rangers meet Maida and set her free from her master, a gambler. The three encounter and manage to enlist the help of an indigenous tribe. Ultimately, the Rangers and the recruited warriors succeed in taking back Free Town.** The regime of terror is overthrown. Both Catch Dog and Black One are killed, and in the midst of combat, also one of the Ranger succumbs to his injuries. In the end, Maida and her daughter can expect a happier future. The two remaining Rangers leave.

A settlement called Free Town -- which contains a refinery -- is attacked by a group of Mad Max-style bikers around the [16:53](https://youtu.be/wlJ48KEZ490?t=1013) mark in the video below. The inhabitants of Free Town manage to repel the bikers with rifles, however they're unable to repel a second assault from a squad of black helmeted troopers carrying bulletproof riot shields, who approach on foot in wall formation around the [23:49](https://youtu.be/wlJ48KEZ490?t=1429) mark.

Comment: Yes.  Looks like it is the one.  I remember it being much higher quality. . Thank you so much.